# Google Action not deploying

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I'm trying to get a simple audio stream playing in a Google Action cloud function. It won't deploy as it says there are errors in the code, but it's not saying where. Here's my code (note the alternatives in *** comments - confusing as I'm not sure which I should be using, having seen both!

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { MediaObject, SimpleResponse } = require('actions-on-google');

const app = actionssdk() // *** or 'const app = conversation()' ?
app.handle("playStream", conv => { // *** or 'app.intent(...' ?
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse("Playing stream"));
    conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: 'My stream',
        url: 'https://stream.redacted.url',
        description: 'The stream',
        icon: new Image({
            url: 'https://image.redacted.url', alt: 'Media icon',
        }),
    }));
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a mix of [`actions-on-google`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) and [`@assistant/conversation`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs) libraries. You should only be using one or the other, depending on what platform you are using.

If you are using the original Actions SDK, you should use `actions-on-google`. If you are using the new Actions SDK or Actions Builder, you should use `@assistant/conversation`.

The distinctions are different but will result in problems. `actionssdk` has an `intent` method but not a `handle` method, and vice versa for `conversation`. This can result in a syntax error. Also make sure you've imported everything, including `Image`.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const {
  conversation,
  Media,
  Image,
} = require('@assistant/conversation')

const app = conversation()
app.handle("playStream", conv => {
    conv.add("Playing stream");
    conv.add(new Media({
      mediaObjects: [{
        name: 'Media name',
        description: 'Media description',
        url: 'https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/cartoon_boing.ogg',
        image: {
          large: new Image({
            url: 'https://image.redacted.url',
            alt: 'Media icon',
          }),
        }
      }],
      mediaType: 'AUDIO',
      optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED']
  }));
})

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

If this still doesn't work, you should add what errors you're seeing in trying to deploy.

Comment: Progress, it's building now, but fails with "not responding" - in logs, I get "TypeError: conv.ask is not a function"

Comment: Ah that's my bad. It's also been renamed to `conv.add` instead of `conv.ask`

Comment: Now I get "TypeError: MediaObject is not a constructor\n    at app.handle.conv"

Comment: Seems like [the way to compose Media](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-conversation-components-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/webhooks/ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment/index.js#L254) has changed as well. I've updated my example.

Comment: Works! Thanks for all your help Nick

Comment: This is far the best example for assistant/conversation. @NickFelker is it also possible to disable seeking controls for the user? Could not find anything in your examples nor in the docs.

Comment: Not to my knowledge